# Reload Suave App on File Save

Tags: .net, f#, suave

I've recently started with Suave; I setup a project using yeoman and the F# generator. To run the app, I build an executable using Fake and then run it. Whenever I change any of the app files, i.e. *.fs files, I have to repeat the process of building and running an executable.

Is there a better process for development, wherein the app rebuilds or reloads/restarts on file save?

Comment: FsReveal's build script does this: https://github.com/fsprojects/FsReveal/blob/master/build.fsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build script for the [F# Snippets project](https://github.com/fssnippets/) does exactly this.

The idea is that you have `app.fsx` file that defines a top-level `WebPart` named `app`. You can see the example for [F# Snippets here](https://github.com/fssnippets/fssnip-website/blob/master/app.fsx#L69). The `app.fsx` script file can also load other files, so you can structure your application in any way you need.

The `build.fsx` [build script](https://github.com/fssnippets/fssnip-website/blob/master/build.fsx#L83) then starts a server,
monitors file system changes for your source code and `app.fsx` and reloads it using [F# Compiler Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/) in the background and replaces the "currently loaded" server with the one obtained from the new `app` value.

The only limitation of the current build script is that it does not correctly relcaim memory (it should probably be fixed by recreating F# Interactive Session in the build script) and so it runs out of memory after a larger number of reloads. But still, it makes the workflow much nicer!

Comment: As I understand it, an alternative is to use script files (.fsx). Is there a "best practice" migration path from a scripted suave app to a compiled one?

Comment: You can setup the project to work both ways. See https://github.com/fssnippets/fssnip-website for example.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar approach to Tomas but run the server in a child process of the build script.  This makes the restart a little bit slower to restart but doesn't leak any memory or ports.  This also lets me easily use a different working directory for my build scripts vs my app scripts (in this case ./app).

Here's a cut down version of my FAKE script.

```
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake

let wait() = System.Console.Read() |> ignore

let runServer () =
    fireAndForget (fun startInfo ->
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory <- "./app"
        startInfo.FileName <- FSIHelper.fsiPath
        startInfo.Arguments <- "--define:RELOAD server.fsx")


Target "Watch" (fun _ ->
  use watcher = !! "app/*.fsx" |> WatchChanges (fun changes ->
      tracefn "%A" changes
      killAllCreatedProcesses()
      runServer()
  )
  runServer()
  wait()
)
```